# Reduction of order and lost in arithmetic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$4x^2y''+4xy'+(4x^2-1)y=0, x>0, y_1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}sinx$

Okay, I am so lost in the arithmetic of this problem.

$y_2(x)= u(x)\frac{sinx}{\sqrt(x)}$ obviously, but I get so lost trying to find the next differential equation. I figure there's no point in calculating $y_2'(x)$ or $y_2''(x)$ because that might be where I'm going wrong, sadly.

Comment: I haven't worked out this problem recently, but, perhaps multiplying by $\sqrt{x}$ then differentiating would make the calculation of $y'$ and $y''$ less annoying. That said, you are aware there is a formula for generating the second solution from the first for such a problem. However,the formula is not easy either. See page 86 of http://www.supermath.info/DifferentialEqns.pdf

Comment: the first step/s are to take the first and second derivative of $y_2$. if you can do that i may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

A simpler approach might be to write $y_2'(x)$ it as:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(u ~\sin x~ x^{-1/2}\right)$$

Now we can just apply the [*Product Rule*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) three times, yielding:

$$\tag 1 \dfrac{u'~\sin x}{x^{1/2}}+\dfrac{u~ \cos x}{x^{1/2}}-\dfrac{u~\sin x}{2 x^{3/2}}$$

Repeating this process again (write the three as products) to find $y_2''(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx}~(1)$ yields:

$$\dfrac{u''~\sin x}{x^{1/2}}-\dfrac{u'~\sin x}{x^{3/2}}+\dfrac{2~u'~\cos x}{x^{1/2}}+\dfrac{3~u~\sin x}{4 x^{5/2}}-\dfrac{u~ \cos x}{x^{3/2}}-\dfrac{u~ \sin x}{x^{1/2}}$$

Can you continue with the [*Reduction of Order*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx) (see examples)?

**Update:**

$4x^2 y''$ yields:

$$\dfrac{4 x^2 \sin x~ u''+8 x^2 \cos x~ u'-4 x \sin x~ u'-4 x^{3/2} ~u ~\cos x+3~ u~ \sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$$

$4 x y'$ yields:

$$\dfrac{2 (2 x \sin x~ u'-u \sin x + 2 x~ u~ \cos x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

$(4x^2 - 1)y$ yields:

$$\dfrac{4 x^2 u \sin x-u \sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Well, I did all of that right. I must have plugged it in incorrectly into the original ODE.... what did you do?

Comment: Ah, no. I got all of that. But I'm missing something when plugging it back in.